# SQL: selecting first occurring line of a repeated value

Tags: mysql, sql

From the following code:

```
SELECT
farm_products.id as ID,  
farm_products.product as Product1,  
shop_products.product as Product2
FROM  
farm_products,  
shop_products,  
shop_farm
WHERE
farm_products.id = shop_farm.farm_id and
shop_farm.farm_id = shop_products.id and 
farm_products.product != shop_products.product;
```

I get the following output:

```
+-------+----------+---------+
|ID     | Product1 | Product2|
+-------+----------+---------+
|06     | 'Apple'  | 'Grape' |
+-------+----------+---------+
|06     | 'Orange' | 'Grape' |
+-------+----------+---------+
|06     | 'Pear'   | 'Apple' |
+-------+----------+---------+
|07     | 'Apple'  | 'Pear'  |
+-------+----------+---------+
|08     | 'Kiwi'   | 'Grape' |
+-------+----------+---------+
|08     | 'Grape'  | 'Orange |
+-------+----------+---------+
```

I want to have a table where only the first occurring line of every
            ID appears.

In other words, I want an output that looks like:

```
+-------+----------+---------+
|ID     | Product1 | Product2|
+-------+----------+---------+
|06     | 'Apple'  | 'Grape' |
+-------+----------+---------+
|07     | 'Apple'  | 'Pear'  |
+-------+----------+---------+
|08     | 'Kiwi'   | 'Grape' |
+-------+----------+---------+
```

I have tried to use **DISTINCT** to remove all the IDs that are repeated, but this (obviously) did not work. 
I want to try to avoid nested queries, and keep the code as simple as possible.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: mysql version ?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin I believe I am using mysql 8.0.13.0

Comment: What exactly is the first table you wrote? Input? Output? Which of the tables you mentioned in your query does it represent?

Comment: @AndrewFan The first table is the output I currently get and the second table is the one I wish to have. The first table is basically the output of my current code, but I want to modify it so that every ID appears only once.

Comment: OK. Please make note of that in your question. I thought the first table was an example of your schema and the second one was your output until I read your query and got confused. Editing the question to make note of what the tables are should reduce potential confusion.

Comment: What determines the first line? data in tables order is not guaranteed so how should this data be sorted why is line 1 of id 06 apple and not orange?

Comment: That query and result don't make much sense to me. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @jarlh I really just want to reduce the first table to the second one, so that each ID appears only once.

Comment: Give us base table data also, and we can write the correct query.

Answer (score 1):

use `row_number()`

```
select * from 
(select *, row_number() over( partition by id order by Product1 ) rn
from table_name
)t where rn=1
```

you can use your query below way

```
 with cte as
(
SELECT
farm_products.id as ID,  
farm_products.product as Product1,  
shop_products.product as Product2,
row_number() over(partition by farm_products.id order by 
 farm_products.product) rn 
FROM  
farm_products join 
shop_products on farm_products.product != shop_products.product
join shop_farm on shop_farm.farm_id = shop_products.id
and farm_products.id = shop_farm.farm_id   

) select * from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: @nikhilsugandh mysql 8+ version support window function

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select * from (SELECT
farm_products.id as ID,  
farm_products.product as Product1,  
shop_products.product as Product2,
row_number() over(partition by farm_products.id order by 
farm_products.id) rank 
FROM  
farm_products,  
shop_products,  
shop_farm
WHERE
farm_products.id = shop_farm.farm_id and  
shop_farm.farm_id = shop_products.id and  
farm_products.product != shop_products.product)
where rank=1
;
```